# how to grab content but nothing class and id using simple html dom

Tags: php, html, dom, curl, simple-html-dom

I have question about simple html dom
question is how to grab content but nothing class and id [ **using simple html dom** ]

for example :

```html
<div style="line-height:15px; float:left; width:100%; margin:2px 0px;">I want grab this text..
<div style="float:left; width:100%; margin-top:5px; font-weight:bold; text-align:left;">text grab2</div>
```

thannks

Comment: at least try *something*

Comment: @Ghost edit and see the real source (i cant get it to display correctly)

Comment: i'm just assuming, you want to get the text inside those div which doesn't have an attribute of `id` and `class`?

Comment: yes, I mean like that but thannks for answer Ghost. I want to get the text inside those div which doesn't have an attribute of id and class?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your example:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

alert(divs[0].innerText);
```

Since your first `<div>` does not have its closing tag, the output would be

`'I want grab this text.. text grab2'`

If you want to get the first `<div>`'s text, just close the tag.

See Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7861d03/)